# Do imports somehow transcend module namespaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, beautifulsoup, python-module

I have a module (say module A) that for one of its functions, returns a BeautifulSoup object. I am writing a second module (module B) that calls this function and stores that BeautifulSoup object. I am confused how I can call BeautifulSoup functions on the object that was returned by module A in module B without module B importing anything from bs4, or having to access those BS4 functions through module A. Is the import basically putting module_a and all of its imports in the package, and so the BeautifulSoup class is visible to module_b?

module_a.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def function():
    some_xml = "<name>Namespaces are strange.</name>"
    return BeautifulSoup(some_xml, "xml")
```

module_b.py

```
import module_a
def main():
    # How does this line know what to do with .find()? or .string?
    print(module_a.function().find("name").string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the beauty of a dynamic language like python. `module_a.function()` tells python to:

- go to module `a`
- lookup a function called "function" and call it
- take the returned object, lookup "find" and call it
- take the returned object, lookup "string" and call it

Since all of these lookups happen dynamically as the function or method is called, `module_b` doesn't have to have a predefined interface for `bs4` or `string`. Its just looking for a method called "find" that could come from anywhere. In fact, `module_a` could swap in some other implementation and as long as the methods being called are still there, it still works.

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` imports the `bs4` module (and any submodules *it* imports) into python. You can see the module in `sys.modules` when its done. It then reaches into `bs4`, looks up `BeautifulSoup` and adds that class to `module_a` 's namespace. The module is now available to all other imported modules... its just that they don't know about it because they haven't imported it. Modules that just use the resulting objects from `bs4` never need to see it directly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I come from a Java background, so I've accepted that some python things are just going to be magic for a while.